# A different way to write the element ID?

Tags: javascript, document, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Below I have this one line of javascript. I want to know if there is another way I can write the `name-id` tag (the element ID). So is there a different way I can write it, would would mean the same thing? Example in ASCII form?

I know in C I could write this in ASCII form.

```
var myname = document.getElementById("name-id").innerHTML;
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. What do you mean "in a different way"? Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All the characters you used appear in ASCII already.

Comment: @jered As in, the line of code I supplied, is there a different way I can write `name-id` and it would still mean `name-id`

Comment: @James — Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is there a different way I can write `name-id` and it would still mean `name-id`? What do you mean?

Comment: `var name_id="name-id"; var myname = document.getElementById(name_id).innerHTML;`

Comment: @Ele like `110, 97, 109, 101, 45, 105, 100` would name `name-id` in ASCII. So is there a different way to write `name-id`? Right now, I can easily tell that I am trying to extract `name-id`. Is there a way where I cannot easily tell that I am trying to extract `name-id`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find technical details of character encoding in current implementation of JavaScript in the official [ECMAScript documentation](http://xahlee.info/javascript_es2016/ECMAScript_2016_Language_Specification.html#sec-ecmascript-language-source-code).

> ECMAScript code is expressed using Unicode, version 8.0.0 or later. ECMAScript source text is a sequence of code points. All Unicode code point values from U+0000 to U+10FFFF, including surrogate code points, may occur in source text where permitted by the ECMAScript grammars.

If less interested in technical aspects and in need of an obfuscator service, just use any of them or compare them. With minimal effort, you can produce something like this:

```js
var _0x2245=['innerHTML','querySelector'],x="tell_me_a_nice_story"
.split("_"),y="#"+x[3][0]+"a"+x[1]+"-"+x[3][1];_0x2245.push(y+"d")
,function(x0,x){!function(x){for(;--x;)x0.push(x0.shift())}(++x)}(
_0x2245,4e3);var _0x1144=function(x0,x0x0){return _0x2245[x0-=0]},
myname=document[_0x1144("0x0")]( _0x1144("0x1"))[_0x2245[+2e0+0]];

console.log(myname);
```

```html
<div id="name-id"
>Why would you do this?
</div>
```

---

If you really want to make it hard for others to read `name-id` in your code, you can do a whole bunch of stuff on it.

You could write something completely different that contains all needed chars or all but one, which you'll add later, split that string into an array using some other unused letter as delimiter, take some array elements from their current position and place them at some other position, join a few, delete others and invert the value of others. Get creative.

By the end of second line above i have `innerHTML`, `querySelector` and `#name-id` as members of the same array.  Only `name-id` was mambo-jambo-ed from `tell_me_a_nice_story` but I could have easily produced `innerHTML` and `querySelector` from a slightly longer text, provided it contained most of the required letters. Think of it as a round of Scrabble.

The last line of the "code block" could be replaced with any of the following:

```
myname=document.getElementById(_0x2245[1].substring(1)).innerHTML;
myname=document.getElementById(_0x1144(1).substring(1)).innerHTML;
myname=document.querySelector(_0x1144(1)||_0x2245(1e0)).innerHTML;
myname=document.querySelector(_0x2245[`1`]||_0x1144(1)).innerHTML;
myname=document[_0x1144(0e3)](_0x2245[1-0]||"\_(ツ)_/").innerHTML;
```

or countless other variants, which "kind of" answer your question and fit the number of chars: `66`.

But, let's be very clear about it: anyone decent in JavaScript will have no problem debugging your code or `console.log()`-ing the result of your final step, to get the value in a matter of seconds.

In all fairness, you ***can't really hide anything in JavaScript (frontend) without a server*** (to run a proper encryption service).

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs automatically become properties in the global `window` object, so you can write:

```
var myname = window['name-id'].innerHTML;
```

And since `window` properties are global variables, you can also access it as a variable, but only if the ID is a valid identifier. Since `-` is not allowed in an identifier name, you can't do this with `name-id`. But if you had:

```
var myname = document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML;
```

you could write it as:

```
var myname = someid.innerHTML;
```

However, I don't really recommend this, I'm just showing it for demonstration purposes. If the element ID is the same as a standard `window` property (e.g. `location` or `document`), the standard property takes precedence.

See [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: What?? I don't understand!

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: What is `var myname = someid.innerHTML`? where is declared someid? Are you trying to say this: `window['someid'] = document.getElementById('someid'); var myname = someid.innerHTML`?

Comment: I said it at the beginning of the answer. If you have an element with `id="someid"`, that automatically creates `window.someid`.

Comment: It's unclear @Barmar

Comment: Have you read the linked question?

Comment: I'm removing my downvote hoping that the OP understands your point.

Comment: It's not clear that this is actually what he's looking for, but it was my best guess.